# Tailwind CSS no autocomplete with 'jit' Just-In-Time mode

Tags: webstorm, jit, tailwind-css, postcss

I am just trying out the new Tailwind CSS 'jit' mode and realized when switched **Webstorm fails to autocomplete** the Tailwind CSS classes.
May there be a fix to this?

my `tailwind.config.js`;

```js
module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  purge: [
    './public/**/*.html',
    './src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,vue}',
  ],
  presets: [],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {...}
...
```

My postcss config (inside nuxt.config.js);

```js
postcss: {
      plugins: {
        'tailwindcss': {},
        '@tailwindcss/jit': {},
        autoprefixer: {},
      }
    }
```

Comment: This question no longer serves any purpose. For Tailwind 3 please refer to the docs. `"mode"` has been removed as `'jit'` is now the default.
`purge` option has been renamed to `content` and is adviced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known issue: with `"jit"` mode, code completion list is very limited, most of applicable CSS classes are not suggested. This will be fixed in the scope of [WEB-50318](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-50318), please follow it for updates.

Note also that, when using latest `tailwindcss` versions, the completion includes unrelated CSS classes from some `*.test.css` files. This will be fixed with the next `tailwindcss` package update, see https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/4393. Workaround: delete `node_modules/tailwindcss/jit/tests/` folder, it's not needed.